# Skip ant target on given timeout

Tags: java, eclipse, build, ant

```
<target name="xtest" depends="xyz" description="Additional check">
    <exec executable="${xtest.exe}" resultproperty="retVal">
        <arg value="123" />
    </exec>
    <echo>Returned: ${retVal}</echo>
</target>
```

Want to skip the "xtest" as success with '[echo] Warning: xtest skipped.' only when taking more than 1 minute.
If within 1 minute "xtest" fails then only process should break.

Comment: Tried with `<parallel threadCount="1" timeout="1000"> <sequential>...`, but it is failing the target. I just want to skip on timeout.

Comment: Try adding `timeout="60000"` and `failonerror="false"` to the `exec` task.

Comment: Thanks @CAustin. I tried the same. Due to `failonerror="false"`, even if execution is failing within the timeout, it continues to process. My condition is, If target fails within timeout then break, if timeout exceeds then skip and continue.

Comment: So you're saying that there's additional code in your "xtest" target that you don't want to run if the xtest.exe process fails? There's no way to continue/break from an Ant target without failing the entire build, short of launching a separate Ant process with the `exec` task (please don't do this). I would suggest breaking up your build logic into multiple targets and controlling whether or not they run with the `if` and `unless` attributes. If you need help with this, I can provide an answer below.